# Data tabulation table

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

basically I need help to display data in a table using the "td" and "tr" tags.

```
html += '<table class="table table-striped">';
for(var i in value){
    if(!number_regex.test(i)){
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        if(i == 'image_link'){
            html += '<td> : ' + '<img src=' + value.image_link + ' alt>' + '</td>';
        }
        else{
            html += '<td> : ' + value[i] + '</td>';
        }
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    }
    html += '</table><br/>';
```

This is my current code where the value is an object. This outputs one "td" in each "tr". I'm trying to align 2 "td"s in one "tr". However, this cannot be accomplished through next(i) or (i+1) as it isn't a number.

This is what I have tried so far to no avail:

```
html += '<td>' + next(i) + '</td>';
if(next(i) == 'image_link'){
    html += '<td> : ' + '<img src=' + value.image_link + ' alt>' + '</td>';
}
else{
    html += '<td> : ' + value[next(i)] + '</td>';
}
```

and:

```
html += '<table class="table table-striped">';
html += '<tr>';
for(var i in value){
    if(!number_regex.test(i)){
        html += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        if(i == 'image_link'){
            html += '<td> : ' + '<img src=' + value.image_link + ' alt>' + '</td>';
        }
        else{
            html += '<td> : ' + value[i] + '</td>';
            console.log(data);
        }
        for(var counter = 0; counter <= 8; counter++){
            //8 because there are 9 fields in the query I want to display
            if(counter % 2 == '0'){ 
                html += '</tr>';
                html += '<tr>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea guys?
These are the additional information that some of you requested:
A picture of the table I have atm:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmhkwturtmcxovh/lala.png
and as for the html, this is a javascript syntax, which is why I'm using html in this manner.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing???

Comment: It would help if you showed what's in `value` and what you want the resulting table to look like.

Comment: You're also missing a bunch of close braces in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a variable and place it in the loop, which does the job of ending the rows by adding `</tr>`...something like :

This is what you have right now :

```
   html += '</tr>';
```

amend it to something like :

```
$var = 0; /* initiaize it somewhere outside for(var i in value) */

if(++$var < 2)
{
     /* do not echo </tr> if 2 td's haven't been added */
}
else /* 2 td's have been added, end this row */
{
 $var = 0; /* reset counter*/ 
 html += '</tr>'; /* end rows */
}
```